# Как сделать замену спомощью регулярки в Qt5 не все выражение, а лишь часть?

Tags: c++, регулярные-выражения, qt5, latex

Есть LaTeX документ, его считываю текстом и ищу по входным заранее определенным данным key_names вхождения типа:
\newcommand{\ValueAxA}[1][-]{#1}
ValueAxA - это key
а значение под key вставляется в #1 (заменяется)

Так вот, можно ли в Qt5 с помощью регулярки как-то просто сделать замену, например с помощью метода replace класса QString. Сложность в том что надо по регулярке находить выражение с подставленным ключем (key), но замену лишь делать в месте метки #1.
А то у меня уже кипит можно конечно тупо сложно парсить посимвольно поиском, охота сделать красиво.

---

В LaTex вообщем создается макроподстановка везде где будет \ValueAxA
параметры:
[1] -количество аргументов;
[- , ...] - аргументы по умолчанию;
#1 - место для вставки 1-го аргумента (если не задан, то аргумента по умолчанию)

Comment: А [std::regex_replace()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/regex_replace) не подойдёт?

Comment: интересно, гляну также, вообще только вернулся к вопросу, скоро будет момент истины:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Просто захватывайте то, что не хотите заменять, при помощи [групп](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D0%B3%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F#%D0%93%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0), и подставляйте потом обратно

```
QRegularExpression re("(.*)ap(.*)");

QString str = "This is an apple";
str.replace(re, "\1exam\2"); //str == "This is an example"
```

Comment: интересно, а в данном случае прочему "This is an example", точка предполагает что любой символ но не пробел, хотя в вики написано что не символ перехода на новую строку... Поидее должен быть просто "//str == "example"", или я чего-то не понимаю, эта регулярка сводит меня с ума)))

Comment: хмм, интересно, мы как бы скобками исключаем части из заменяемого

Comment: Получилось что-то вроде
`foreach(QString key, keys) {
   //qDebug() << key << ":" << obj.value(key).toString();
   new_tex_data_fragment.replace(QRegExp(QString("(\\\\newcommand\\{\\\\%1\\}\\[\\d{0,2}\\]\\[[- а-яА-Яa-zA-Z0-9]*\\]\\s*\\{)#1(\\})").arg(key)), "\\1TEST\\2"); 
  }`

Comment: правда появилась сложность что в значениях по умолчанию если тоже макросы находятся то все ломается, выход - не писать там макросы)

Comment: "точка предполагает что любой символ но не пробел" - никогда такого не слышал. Точка может быть пробелом. "мы как бы скобками исключаем части из заменяемого" - это я так их использовал, а вообще мы скобками [указываем](https://regex101.com/r/8EkUh5/1) ту часть, которую хотим запомнить, потом в выражении замены можем подставлять содержимое скобок при помощи `\1, \2, ...`.